# Why do the arguments of the sum function need to be in parentheses?

Tags: python

Why does `sum(1,2)`  lead to `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, and `sum(1,2,3)`  lead to `TypeError: sum expected at most 2 arguments, got 3`, but it's OK if I add more parentheses?

```
sum((1,2,3))
```

Meanwhile,  `max(1,2,3)` and `max((1,2,3))`  are all OK.

Comment: They're different functions, and they accept different arguments. [sum takes an iterable plus an optional starting value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) while [max takes an iterable or a set of values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences for differences

Comment: @jakevdp you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because python built in function sum() takes an argument of a iterable and a second argument of starting position in the iterable. sum(iterable[, start])

This is why adding 3 arguments give you an error. you can read more in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum

max() on the other hand accepts argument differently, max(iterable[, key]) and
max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key]) as found in https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max
It can accept both an iterable or a bunch of numbers as arguments and return the max.

Answer (score 2):

`sum` takes one mandatory argument which needs to be any sequence of numbers i.e. list or tuple (but not string) of numbers.

An optional second argument would be added to the result if given.

```
>>> sum((1, 2, 3))
6
>>> sum([1, 2, 3])
6
>>> sum((1, 2, 3), 4)
10
>>> sum([1, 2, 3], 4)
10
```

Answer (score 0):

"Sums start and the items of an **iterable** from left to right and returns the total."
Just to prove it and perhaps mess with your sanity:

```
>>> type ((1))
<type 'int'>
>>> sum ((1),2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

>>> type ((1,))
<type 'tuple'>
>>> sum ((1,),2)
3

>>> type ([1])
<type 'list'>
>>> sum ([1],2)
3

>>> type ([1,])
<type 'list'>
>>> sum ([1,],2)
3
>>>
```